# InDesign: Anchored text frame in book layout with border styles relative to the spine?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm working on a book layout and I need a way to create an anchored text box that has a thicker border on the page edge, sort of like this:

[image]

I've looked at the border options and there doesn't seem to be a way to set an edge border relative to the spine, so I thought about just creating a rectangle shape and anchoring it to the text box, which is then anchored to the main text. This works, but the height of the rectangle doesn't match the text box unless I manually set it. I have many of these anchored text boxes so in a perfect world I'd be able to set the border in a paragraph style or something, but if I'm going to have to go through and anchor a rectangle to every single one and manually make the height match then so be it. But if anyone can think of a better way that'd be helpful!

Comment: Could use a Table with 1 cell, and a set border on the side.

Comment: @Scott, good idea. That would require manually setting a different Cell Style on the cell for left and right pages. But easy to set up. It's also possible to use an offset *Column Rule* on the text frames. Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/S99LcFY.gif). It's more hacky to set up, but it only requires setting an Object Style on each anchored text frame. Just a tiny bit quicker. The question is if the OP is still interested?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I ended up just creating a black box and anchoring it to the text frame relative to the spine. I have to copy the entire group of elements and manually match the length of the box every time I need a new one, but it works okay because I can just manually fix the length of the box if I adjust the text. Not ideal but since I'm not working with a team it's not a huge deal.

Answer (score 0):

Possible alternative: in ID "Master Pages" by creating a secondary set of master pages specifically for that text box (with its boxed shapes and tones) and link it to the specific pages you need (assuming you're needing it just for certain pages in the book).